# Get first record from each groups without using ROW_NUMBER() or RANK()

Tags: sql, hiveql

Due Hive software constraints, I don't have the luxury of using RANK(), PARTITION BY, and OVER().

What I want to do is retrieve the first row from each group.

The table schema is as follows:

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'prod_id', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'brand', 'varchar(20)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'name', 'varchar(75)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'price', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'cost', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'shipping_wt', 'smallint(6)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

My current solution via SQL is:

```
select brand,name,price from 
(select brand,name,price,row_number() 
over(partition by brand order by price desc) as rn 
from products) as sub 
where rn=1;
```

How do I do so without the aforementioned functions and keywords?

Comment: What do you mean "due to Hive software constraints"?  Those functions have been part of Hive for a long, long time.

Comment: Not in Hive 0.10, window functions were officially supported as of 0.11 onwards. link - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Comment: . . Hive 0.11 was released in 2013.  That is a long time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` and aggregation:

```
select p.*
from products p join
     (select p.brand, min(p.price) as min_price
      from products p
      group by p.brand
     ) pp
     on p.brand = pp.brand and p.price = pp.min_price;
```

This is actually equivalent to `rank()` rather than `row_number()`, but it is the same if there are no duplicate prices.

I strongly recommend using the window functions, though.  Not only are they standard and an integral part of Hive, but they should be faster too.

Comment: I understand. It really grieves me to be unable to use the window functions. Thank you for your help.